# Show News Item creator or owner full name in Plone

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I'm trying to show the full name for each news item in a list. For the moment I have only the user id (nickname).

Is there a simple way (in existing .pt file) to show the full name of creator or owner instead of a nickname?

The page must work for anonymous users, too. I mean - the page must be public.

Some details:

```
<div class="container-fluid news-list-container"
     tal:define="news_items python:context.getFolderContents(contentFilter={'portal_type':['News Item'], 'sort_on': 'Date', 'sort_order': 'descending',});
                 Batch python:modules['Products.CMFPlone'].Batch;
                 b_size python:4;
                 b_start python:0;
                 b_start request/b_start | b_start;
                 batch python:Batch(news_items, b_size, int(b_start), orphan=0);"
     tal:condition="news_items">

  <div class="news-list-items">

    <tal:items tal:repeat="news_item batch">

      <!-- News item -->
      <div class="row news-item"
           tal:define="news_object python:news_item.getObject();
                       news_date python:news_object.getField('modification_date').getAccessor(news_object)();
                       news_title python:news_object.getField('title').getAccessor(news_object)();
                       news_description python:news_object.getField('description').getAccessor(news_object)();
                       news_image python:news_object.getField('image').getAccessor(news_object)();
                       news_url python:news_object.absolute_url();
                       news_creators python:news_object.getField('creators').getAccessor(news_object)(); .... ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<tal:fullname define="membership context/portal_membership;
                      info python:membership.getMemberInfo(user.getId());
                      fullname info/fullname">
    You are are <span class="name" tal:content="fullname" />
</tal:fullname>
```

This example is taken from the  [plone documentation](http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/members/member_profile.html#getting-member-fullname)

Comment: The best. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can get inspired a lot by this code:

- https://github.com/collective/Products.Scrawl/blob/1021047c4ef6c2655d104e8b345a24140da9e4aa/Products/Scrawl/browser/blogentry_view.pt#L32

  ```
      <tal:name tal:condition="item_creator"
          tal:define="author python:context.portal_membership.getMemberInfo(item_creator)">
        <span i18n:translate="label_by_author">Posted by
        <a href="#"
           title="Read more posts by this author"
           tal:attributes="href string:${context/portal_url}/author/${item_creator}"
           tal:content="python:author and author['fullname'] or item_creator"
           tal:omit-tag="not:author"
           i18n:domain="scrawl"
           i18n:name="author"
           i18n:attributes="title author_title">
          Bob Dobalina
        </a>
        </span>
      </tal:name>
  ```

Mind the possible performance issues.

A cached view method may work a lot better, e.g.:

```
@memoize
def userid2fullname(self, userid):
     pm = api.portal.get_tool('portal_membership')
     memberinfo = pm.getMemberInfo(userid)
     return memberinfo and memberinfo['fullname'] or userid
```

Comment: I go it half ready before @mathias replied. It is basically the same but points  to a similar use case and warns about performances, So I am posting anyway :p